# find first row count and second row count using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mySql. I need to find how much entry in table which have entered only one time and another records which are enter for second time. please see the screenshot. count is based on shg_id.

[image]

Comment: why some one give this question minus rank ?

Answer (score 2):

The following should do if it has an id attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
HAVING COUNT(shg_id) = 1 -- Record equal to 1
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM Table
HAVING COUNT(shg_id) = 2 -- Record equal to 2
```

**Updated** - This works well on my side:

```
SELECT COUNT(shg_id) AS Total 
FROM Table
WHERE shg_id= 4
GROUP BY shg_idHAVING COUNT(shg_id) = 1
```

**Another one** - Slightly taken from OTARIKI:

```
SELECT shg_id, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM Table
GROUP BY shg_id
HAVING COUNT(shg_id) BETWEEN 1 and 2
```

Comment: SELECT     
    COUNT(sbl.shg_id) AS total_shg 
  FROM
    `shg_bank_loan` AS sbl 
  WHERE  1 =1 
  GROUP BY sbl.`shg_id` 
HAVING COUNT(sbl.`shg_id`) = 1

I am using group by then it is returning me the multiple results. can it is possible it is return only count  without any other ouery

Comment: Count without any other query? Like what - Could you specify a bit more?

Comment: query which I written given the like 41 rows. I need only 41 count not rows. without group by query is not working

Comment: See my post and I've updated that works well on my side.

Comment: Your updated query also returning multiple rows. for single row I put this query in another select query.

Comment: Yes. Cause you are dealing with ids and every id should have its own records. That's why you get those results. For a single id, you are getting the perfect count..

Answer (score 2):

if I correctly understand, you need this:

```
select entered, count(*) from (
    select shg_id, count(*) as entered 
    FROM mytable 
    group by shg_id 
    having count(*) between 1 and 2
)t
group by entered
```

Comment: This will return multiple rows.

Comment: @AT-2016 this returns 2 row, 1)   unique shg_id rows count and 2) `two times repeated` shg_id count

Comment: OK. Got it. Good one.